# Mostrar registros en tabla PDO

Tags: html5, php7

Trato de mostrar los registros de una tabla con PDO es un (CRUD), pero me esta arrojando error, en la linea del query. No se si el método que estoy usando es el correcto o este mal la sintaxis del código.

Espero puedan ayudarme, este es el código que estoy usando:

```
<?php
include("conexion.php");
$registros=$sql->query("select * from libros")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

if(isset($_POST['cr']))
{
    $nombre=$_POST["Nom"];
    $autor=$_POST["Aut"];
    $genero=$_POST["Gen"];
    $cantidad=$_POST["Can"];
$precio=$_POST["Pre"];
$sql="INSERT INTO libros (Nombre,Autor,Genero,Cantidad,Precio) VALUES (:nom, :aut, :gen, :can, :pre )";
    $resultado=$base->prepare($sql);
    $resultado->execute(array("nom"=>$nombre,":aut"=>$autor,":gen"=>$genero,":can"=>$cantidad,":pre"=>$precio ));
    header("Location:index.php");
}
```

?>

Y este mi archivo de conexión:

```
<?php

define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
define('DB_NAME', 'catalagolib');


try{
    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=" . DB_SERVER . ";dbname=" . DB_NAME, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD);

    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch(PDOException $e){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . $e->getMessage());
}
?>
```

Este es el error

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetchAll() on
>   string in C:\xampp\htdocs\Projects\UTCJ\CRUD.php on line 27 ( ! )
>   Error: Call to a member function fetchAll() on string in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Projects\UTCJ\CRUD.php on line 27

La linea 27 seria esta:

```
$registros=$sql->query("select * from libros")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

Comment: cual es el error que te aparece?

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetchAll() on string in C:\xampp\htdocs\Projects\UTCJ\CRUD.php on line 27
( ! ) Error: Call to a member function fetchAll() on string in C:\xampp\htdocs\Projects\UTCJ\CRUD.php on line 27
La linea 27 seria esta:
$registros=$sql->query("select * from libros")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
@anonimo

Comment: la variable `$sql` en tu `SELECT` de donde viene?

Comment: Uff, gracias @anonimo tenia mal asignada esa variable.
Ya la corregi y funciona a la prefección.